# What unit system puts a bunch of powers of ten in Maxwell's equations?

Tags: electromagnetism, units, maxwell-equations, unit-conversion

In what unit system can we get the Maxwell equation in the following form (section 1.2 from Lewin's book *Advanced Theory of Waveguide*)

$$\nabla\times \vec E = -10^8\mu \frac{\partial \vec H} {\partial t}$$

and

$$\nabla \times \vec H = \frac{1}{9\cdot 10^{12}}\epsilon '\frac{\partial \vec E} {\partial t}+\frac{4}{10}\pi \vec J \, ?$$

It seems neither CGS nor SI.

Comment: That should be a $\partial\vec{E}/\partial t$, no?

Comment: This section here might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz%E2%80%93Heaviside_units#Rationalization

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This post had a lot of irrelevant parts and distracting formatting, so I removed it. Please note that the clarity is the most important aspect of writing a good question. You do not need to thank the reader or put words in bold. We're here to answer questions because we understand physics and *want to help you*, so bolding the words and thanking us is really just distracting.